# Handling string with double quotes in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a runtime parameter with value like '2017-01-01','2017-01-02'

And i want to split this parameter as a string with two values and use as filter in my query..say using lateral view explode and the new alias should hv values like below

After split

```
2017-01-01
2017-01-02
```

how do i do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Before asking a question, try to solve the problem and show what you have tried in your post.  See this link for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You seem to understand you need lateral view and explode, so have you tried using a string function to split on the comma?